# Regex that matches anything not ending in .json

Tags: javascript, regex, express

For a web app I'm trying to come up with a javascript regex that matches anything not ending in `.json`. Sounds simple but I'm finding it pretty damn hard.

I first wanted to do it like this: `^.*(?!\.json$)`, but that obviously didn't work as it simply matches the entire string. Then I tried `^[^\.]*(?!\.json$)` but that matches `ab` in `abc.json`.

I've come so far as to come up with two regexes that do the job, but I want to have one regex that can do this.

```
// Match anything that has a dot but does not end in .json
^.*\.(?!json$)
// Match anything that doesn't have a dot
^[^\.]*$
```

I like http://regex101.com/#javascript to test them.

I am using the regexp as part of ExpressJS route definition in `app.get(REGEXP, routes.index)`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try `/^(?!.*\.json$).*$/`

```
/^(?!.*\.json$).*$/.test("foo.json")
false
/^(?!.*\.json$).*$/.test("foo")
true
/^(?!.*\.json$).*$/.test("foo.html")
true
```

Comment: @TheFonz: You should still consider the other option in the other two answers. Perfectly valid point about code readability.

Answer (score 1):

You can always just get the file extension and then compare it.

Regex to find file extension

`/\.[^.]*$/`

get the file extension with

```
var extension = /\.[^.]*$/.exec("something.json");

if(extension[0] === ".json"){
    //do something
}
```

Comment: Good point. Elegant solution. Would certainly consider that if I weren't using Express.js's `app.get(REGEX, routes.index);` syntax.

Comment: Oh well that changes things. Yea well I guess I would go with the other answers here

Answer (score -1):

maybe instead of testing "match (not .json)" you could test "not match (.json)", which is easy ?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'd do that if I didn't want to use Express.js's `app.get(REGEX, routes.index);`

Comment: @TheFonz: Correct me if I'm wrong, but couldn't you have made the extension an optional parameter and tested if it's '.json'? EDIT: For instance `/foo(\.\w+)?/`

Comment: Yes, but I'm not sure how that would work with the function in the comment above... it's easier to just use the regex. Also the filename can be anything.

Comment: @TheFonz: With the exact regexp I provided, you would access the extensions as `req.params[0]`. If you want to also catch the filename as first parameter (e.g., `/([^.])(\.\w+)?/`) then extension is `req.params[1]`. See http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.VERB.

Comment: @bvukelic Ah I see what you mean now. Yes that'd work great as well. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score -1):

I would create a regex to match .json and then when you check for it reverse the logic with a

> match == false

That would be much simpler and it shows what you are trying to do making it a lot more obvious to other programmers.

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted, but this is a pretty logical solution. It's not strictly regex, but it's valid.

Comment: Unless their question is only part of a larger regex they need - for instance, maybe they need to match parts of the filename for later extraction; if you only match that it hit JSON and then deny it, you can't combine those. With a negative lookahead, you can.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Can't do that too easily, I'm using Express.js and want to use the `app.get(REGEX, routes.index);` syntax