# JavaScript RegEx not ending with (.js|.jsx|.scss)

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I want to implement a JavaScript RegEx that not ending with (.js|.jsx|.scss), execution result like below, but no operator `!` before RegEx.

```
!/(.js|.jsx|.scss)$/
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex that matches anything not ending in .json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21962329/regex-that-matches-anything-not-ending-in-json) and [Regex for matching string not ending or containing file extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39007246)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use a negative look ahead with alternations to reject the strings that end with those extensions you mentioned in your post. Try this regex,

```
^(?!.*(?:\.jsx?|\.scss)$).*$
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/TTWXhF/1)**

```js
var arr = ['abc.js','xyz.jsx','ddd.scss','abc.jsa','xyz.jsxa','ddd.scssd'];

for (s of arr) {
console.log(s+' --> '+/^(?!.*(?:\.jsx?|\.scss)$).*$/.test(s));
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. I want to know why `?:` is required in the given RegEx? If `?:` removed, it could also work well.

Comment: @licaomeng: `?:` is just used to make a group as non-capturing group as by default a group `()` is a capturing one and yes without `?:` also it will work fine. In general it is a good practice to make a group as non-capturing unless you really need the group (say for back referencing or group text capture) as it makes the group more performant.

Comment: It is clear now, thank you.

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
^(?!.*\.(?:jsx?|scss)$).*$
```

- `^` - Anchor to start of string.
- `(?!.*\.(?:jsx?|scss)$).*` - Condition to check `jsx, js and scss`
- `$` - End of string.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kp10Pt/4/)